# Problem With <hr>

Tags: html, css

Any ideas why the `<hr>` in [this post](http://www.glamourunderground.com/how-to-start-running/) won't go under the photo while the `<hr>` in [this post](http://www.glamourunderground.com/review-shock-absorber-run-sports-bra-b5044/) will?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing? I can't see any problems with any `hr` elements in the first post (or the second, but that was the point). Also, what browser/OS are you using? It seems to look fine on Chromium 10 and Firefox 4/Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: What `<hr>` are you talking about? All of the headers I can see seem to be above the pictures (none of them are below). I am guessing its a css `position` issue. Could you post the css/html for whatever `<hr>` your talking about?

Comment: @SsRide30, it is `<hr>` as in Horizontal Rule, not headings. In the non-working version you can see to the right of the image a a small part of an `<hr>` coming out from behind it.

Comment: @David Thanks for the reply. I'm using the latest Chrome w/ Windows. [Here](http://www.glamourunderground.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/hr-problem.png) is a screenshot with the problem highlighted. 

In the first post, the '<hr>' is showing behind the photo rather than under it like it is in the second post.

Comment: Can you post the "before" CSS and HTML code into this question so that it is useful to future visitors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because the image in the non-working version is floated left. which makes its container not re-size to fit the contents..

***In detail***

The working version has the class `.aligncenter` applied, while the failing version has `.alignleft` which floats the element to the left with the `float:left` property setting.

if you remove the `float:left` it will work (*or alternatively set the `clear:both` for the `hr` element, as @pekka mentioned*).

Comment: @everyone Thank you! I set the img to 'float:center' and it works now.

Comment: @Tara: `float: center` doesn't exist (as a real value for `float`, anyway). If you're using that, you may as well remove the `float` declaration, since it isn't, or shouldn't, be doing anything...

Answer (score 1):

Your image has `float: left`, causing the `hr` to start on the same line as the image.

Giving the `hr`

```
clear: both
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Because the images doesn't have the same class.